# Relationship within a relationship in Access 2010 Web Database

Tags: database, web, relationship, ms-access-2010, lookup

I am trying to build a web database that I can run through Sharepoint.  I read through the documentation for following the rules of web databases.  I am running into trouble with relationships even though I followed the rules.  Here's the situation...

I have 3 tables.  One is called Vehicles, one Feature Availability, and the third Availability Type.  The first table lists all vehicles with model information, etc.  The Feature Availability uses a lookup to the Vehicle ID to relate each vehicle to its available features.  Then in the Availability Type table, I used another lookup field that uses FeatureAvailabilityID to link the features to their type (standard, optional, etc).

When I first did this, it automatically created subdatasheets so I was able to click the plus sign on a vehicle in the vehicles table and it expanded the available features and then I could expand on the available features to see the availability type.  So my relationship structure is how I want it.  However, when I ran the compatibility check, I got errors telling me to remove the subdatasheets so I did.  The relationships still remained in tact and I ran compatibility check again.  I get the following error:  ACCWEB105016: "Relationships that are not associated with a Web-compatible lookup are incompatible with the Web"  for the FeatureAvailabilityID.  The thing that has me stumped is that the relationship is created through a lookup.

The only thing I can think of is that Access doesn't allow me to create a "relationship within a relationship" since Feature Availablity is on the many side of the relationship with vehicles and the one side of Availability type.  If this is true, then Access web database is pretty much useless for most applications.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?